# How can one prove that $\int \langle x,y\rangle d\gamma’ = \int \langle x-\tau,y-\tau' \rangle d\gamma$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, optimal-transport, coupling

I'm reading the book Computational Optimal Transport, by Peyré and Cuturi. In the book, in Remark 2.19 the authors make a claim regarding the translation of measures. While trying to prove the remark, I was faced with the following identity to be proven:

Let $\gamma$ be a coupling of $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $\gamma’$ be a coupling of $(T_{\tau\#}\alpha,T_{\tau'\#}\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are probability measures in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Also, note the following:

- Coupling - It means that the marginal distributions of $\gamma’$ are $T_{\tau\#}\alpha$ for the project on $X$ and $T_{\tau'\#}\beta$ for the projection on $Y$;
- $T_\tau(x) = x-\tau ,\quad T_{\tau'}(y) = y - \tau'$;
- $\int f(x) d T_{\tau\#}\alpha = \int f(T(x)) d\alpha$.

With all this being said, how does one proves that:
$$
\int \langle x,y\rangle d\gamma’ = \int\langle x-\tau,y-\tau'\rangle d\gamma
$$

Comment: Still, I'd say this is not correct. What you can prove presumably (and which is sufficient for the argument in Remark 2.19) is that for every coupling $\gamma'$ there exists a coupling $\gamma$ (and vice versa) such that your idendity holds.

Comment: I see. How would you prove your assertion?

Comment: Would it be indeed sufficient for 2.19? Because I’m assuming that $\gamma$ is the optimal map.

Comment: if $\gamma$ is coupling between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then $\gamma':=T_{(\tau,\tau')\#}\gamma$ is a coupling between the respective push forwards of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I see your point! Thanks!

Comment: when they say "$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are probability measures in $X$ and $Y$", is this the same as saying "$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the *probability distributions* of $X$ and $Y$"?

Comment: Not really. $X$ and $Y$ are the underlying metric space, not random variables. If I define $X= \mathbb R$ and $\alpha$ a measure equal to 0.5 for $x=0$ and 0.5 for $x=1$. Note that $\alpha$ is not the distribution of $\mathbb R$